# Javascript Addition (add 10 to an interger)?

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me how to use addition in JavaScript ?

For example :

- I want to add 10 to an existing element class as "box" which contains an integer of 5.
- I want the JavaScript to add 10 to the number 5 and make it into 15.

Anyone can help me with this simple script?

Comment: I wonder if I'm missing something obvious, `box.i+=10;` should do it.

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question.

Comment: Use `parseInt` for taking the integer from the string (the value of the element).

Comment: @Blindy: He probably wants to `parseInt` `.value`, add `5`, and set it again

Comment: @SLaks, but I thought that adding an integer to a string coerces the string to an integer too in Javascript.

Comment: [Arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Arithmetic_Operators)

Comment: whats the difference between .i+=10; and parseInt? sorry for asking stupid questions

Comment: DOM elements' values are strings, not numbers.  `parseInt` parses a string to a number.  Make sure to pass `10` as the second parameter to specify the base

Comment: But I wanna know how to add numbers in jQuery??

Comment: @edward: [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) parses a string to an integer (if possible). `box.i += 10` adds `10` to the value hold in the property `i` of the object `box`.

Comment: You have to be more specific if you want better help. Do you want to add a value to a number that is the value of a DOM element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
// assuming that there are many divs with .box class
$("div.box").each(function(idx,elem){
  $(this).text( parseInt($(this).text(),10) +10 );
});
```

[simple example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7KB4g/)

Comment: always specify the radix for parseInt, in the case parseInt(($this).text(), 10) + 10

Comment: Or shorter: `$("div.box").text(function(i, v){ return +v + 10;});` But the question was no about jQuery!

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for the deep and dark secrets of the `+` operator.

Comment: sorry about this stupid question. thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator '+'. But be aware that javascript can make some bizarre results if the value is not an instance of Integer. So make sure of that!

```
var INTEGER_VALUE = 5; var STRING_VALUE = "5";
var result_1 = INTEGER_VALUE + 10; //15
var result_2 = parseInt(STRING_VALUE) + 10; //15
var result_3 = STRING_VALUE + 10; //"510"
```

Comment: always specify the radix for parseInt, in the case parseInt(STRING_VALUE, 10) + 10